# PS get-content high memory usage - Is there a more efficient way to filter a file?

Tags: powershell

I am using get-content to read a largish file (252 MB), but when I use get-content to read it, the powershell process proceeds to consume almost 10 GB of memory. Is this normal behavior?

The array has just shy of 6 million items. It doesn't seem to be remotely in line with the amount of memory being used.

Maybe I'm just going about this the wrong way entirely.

I want to write the line that matches a string and the subsequent line to a new text file.

```
$mytext = get-content $inpath
$search = "*tacos*"
$myindex = 0..($mytext.count - 1) | Where {$mytext[$_] -like $search}
$outtext = @()
foreach ($i in $myindex){
    $outtext = $outtext + $mytext[$i] + $mytext[$i+1]
    }
$outtext | out-file -filepath $outpath
```

## Performance Testing Results

I took a performance sample for different scripts based on different answers here.

**My original script**

(highly sensitive to the number of lines that get written out)

- 10k lines - 1.8s
- 100k lines - 38s
- 100k lines - 21s (when search string occurs rarely)
- 5000k lines - Too long to measure (aborted after several hours)

**Select-String with no Get-Content (adapted from [whatever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38873560/598943))**

`Select-String -path $inpath -pattern $search -Context 0,1 -SimpleMatch | Out-File $outpath`

- 10k lines - 1.2s
- 100k lines -  4s
- **1000k lines - 107s**

Note processing speed only grows by a factor of ~4 for a 10x increase in input. The more data you try to process at once, the better this solution becomes relative to the others.

**Eliminating the array resize (from Mathias)**

- 10k lines - 2.0s
- 100k lines - 25s
- 1000k lines - 1533s (using 1.7GB memory, the same as running gc outside of the script on 1000k lines)

**Using the pipeline (from Chris Dent)**

- 100k lines - 26s

Comment: There's not a single instance of `Get-Content` in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is Select-String:

```
$search = "tacos"
Get-Content $inpath | Select-String $search -Context 0,1 | Out-File $OutputFile -Append
```

However, this will produce slightly changed output:

```
match
following line
```

will turn into

```
> match
  following line
```

if you want the exact lines from the file:

```
Get-Content $inpath | Select-String $search -Context 0,1 | foreach {$_.Line | Out-File $OutputFile -Append ; $_.Context.Postcontext |  Out-File $OutputFile -Append}
```

Btw: Get-Content gets kinda slow once files get really big. Once that happens it might be better to do:

```
$TMPVar = Get-Content $inpath -Readcount 0
$TMPVar | Select-String....
```

This will make Get-Content read the entire file at once instead of line by line which is much faster but needs a bit more memory than piping it directly into the next cmdlets.

Comment: The get-content command in my original example was responsible for the insane memory consumption. It was using nearly 10GB to read a 260MB file. I ran it alone and still got the same memory usage. Seems like I need a solution that avoids get-content altogether.

Comment: Select-String can read from the file directly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916650/piping-files-to-get-content?rq=1
`Select-String -path $inpath -pattern $search -Context 0,1 -SimpleMatch | Out-File $outpath`

Comment: 10gb seems really excessive, did a quick benchmark with a ~220MB textfile (only reading the file and select-string, no writing it to disk):  $var = get-content; $var | select-string took 200s and 3GB of ram, get-content | select-string 37s 70mb,
$var = get-content -readcount 0 ; $var | select-string
19s 430mb
select-string -inputobject (get-item)
3s 120mb (!)
So using select-string with the file as inputobject like you suggested in your last comment really seems to be the best way by far. I didn't test the other variants in this topic, maybe they are even better...

Comment: I tested again today with 1M line files (about 90M) and get-content consumes 1.7GB of RAM when run on that file. I also added some testing results above. Select-String on the file literally blows all other methods out of the water!

Comment: Thanks for posting the speeds, quite interesting. I found one more thing you might be able to do if you really are looking for maximum performance: `Add-Content -Path $inpath -Value (Select-String -path $inpath -pattern $search -Context 0,1 -SimpleMatch)` seems to outperform "| Out-File" quite a bit :) (~4s vs 7s when exporting 20000 matches from a 3 million line file). Probably way past the point of diminishing returns, but I was curious...

Answer (score 4):

> process proceeds to consume almost 10 GB of memory. [...] The array has just shy of 6 million items. It doesn't seem to be remotely in line with the amount of memory being used.

`Get-Content` against a file of 6 million lines results in 6 million string objects - and allocating a string object is not just allocating memory for the characters themselves but also an object header and additional overhead.

That would only account for about 5-10% of what you're seeing though - the real problem is this construct:

```
$outtext = @() # this
foreach ($i in $myindex){
    $outtext = $outtext + $mytext[$i] + $mytext[$i+1] # and this
}
```

Every time you re-assign the values of the array like that, the underlying array has to be resized, causing .NET to copy the contents to *a new array*.

Change it to:

```
$outtext = foreach ($i in $myindex){
    $mytext[$i],$mytext[$i+1]
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this `$outtext = @()`, if you reassign variable on next line?

Comment: @PetSerAl I don't, my fat fingers simply don't copy-paste that well

Comment: This cut my execution time in half for a 10k line file. 710ms to 349.

Comment: Not surprised :-) how about memory consumption?

Answer (score 2):

The pipeline is your friend. There's no advantage to be gained from your indexing process other than making it take longer and add more into memory.

This gets the line you're searching for, plus the one line of context you need (from the example). Nothing is loaded into memory except the items that match your search plus that one line.

```
$getNext = $false
$outtext = Get-Content $inPath | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -like $search) {
        $_
        $getNext = $true
    }
    elseif ($getNext) { #reads the following line on next iteration
        $_
        $getNext = $false
    }
}
```